# Given two curves(both formed of certain points)，firgure out point count of one curve over another

Tags: visual-c++, point, curve

[image]

As the pic show, both curves are of spline line, and have limited points. I want to figure out the count of green points. Is there any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I assume the black curve is x-monotone (otherwise the "one above the other" term can be ambiguous).

A simple approach is to consider the black curve as a polygonal line and for each point `p` on the red curve find the point `q` on the polygonal line with the same x-coordinate. Then the green points are those `p` that have a larger y-coordinate than their corresponding `q`.

Finding the point `q` corresponding to a given `p` amounts to going over the segments of the polygonal line and identifying segments that have one endpoint with smaller x-coordinate and the other with larger. Once you have such a segment the y-value of `q` is just a linear interpolation.

Since the polygonal line is x-monotone, the x-coordinates of the points are sorted. Therefore, the search for the corresponding segments can be done efficiently using logarithmic binary-search.